# create_taskに変数を渡す際にコピーを発生させたくない。

Tags: c++

###### 目的

C++のcreate_taskを使用しています。
外から渡すデータをcopyではなくmoveさせたい。

###### 質問

create_taskに渡す際に、コピーを発生させないようにstd::move動作させると、１回ムーブ後に、複数回コピーコンストラクタが実行されます。
別質問にて、create_taskのラムダがコピーされているのでコピーが発生していると教えていただいたのですが、しかし１回はともかく、複数回は多いです。これはどうしようもないでしょうか？

```
struct Test
{
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> data; // データ
  int value;

  Test(std::unique_ptr<int[]>&& d)
    : data(std::forward<std::unique_ptr<int[]>>(d))
    , value(10)
  {
  }

  Test(const Test& _obj)
  {
    value = _obj.value;
    ::OutputDebugStringW(L"コピー\n");
  }

  Test(Test&& _obj) noexcept
    : data(std::forward<std::unique_ptr<int[]>>(_obj.data))
    , value(_obj.value)
  {
    ::OutputDebugStringW(L"ムーブ\n");
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> data = std::make_unique<int[]>(10);
  Test sample(std::move(data));
  std::vector<Test> List;
  List.emplace_back(std::move(sample));
  pplx::create_task([test_c = std::forward<std::vector<Test>>(List), 10]()
  { 
  });
  List.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pplx::create_task`を簡単に説明している [Programming with Tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Programming-with-Tasks) の末尾にちょろっとリンクがありますが、`pplx::create_task`の元ネタとなった [タスクの並列化 (コンカレンシー ランタイム)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/parallel/concrt/task-parallelism-concurrency-runtime?view=msvc-170) が参考になるかと思います。

> 一般的なパターンは、継続のチェーンの 1 つのタスクが変数に割り当てられ、別のタスクがその変数を読み取る場合です。 各継続タスクが変数のそれぞれのコピーを保持するため、値によるキャプチャができません。 スタック割り当て変数においても、変数が有効でなくなる場合があるため、参照によるキャプチャができません。
>
> この問題を解決するには、std::shared_ptr などのスマート ポインターを使用し、変数をラップして、スマート ポインターを値で渡します。 この方法を使用すると、基になるオブジェクトが割り当てられ、読み込むことができ、それを使用するタスクのために十分な有効期間となります。

と`std::shared_ptr`の利用が提案されています。（`std::unique_ptr`でなく）`std::shared_ptr`でオブジェクトを保持した場合、`std::shared_ptr`そのものはコピーされますが、保持したオブジェクトはコピーもムーブもされないため、今回の要件を満たすかと思います。

Comment: 前回に引き続きありがとうございます。
なるほど、std::shared_ptrを使用すれば、元の変数のスコープが終わっても、タスクで使用している間はメモリが確保され続ける。ということですね！
試したところうまくいきました。本当にありがとうございます。